# LNK1104 Error when trying to setup SFML 2.3.1 in MS Visual Studio COmmunity 2015

Tags: sfml

I'm no expert in programming, and have never used SFML previously, but thought I would give it a try for fun tonight. I followed the instructions on the sfml-dev.org, but when I try to run the testprogram that's supposed to render a circle, I get the following build error:

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'sfml-graphics-s-d.lib
>   sfml-window-s-d.lib sfml-system-s-d.lib sfml-audio-s-d.lib
>   sfml-network-s-d.lib opengl32.lib freetype.lib jpeg.lib winmm.lib
>   gdi32.lib openal32.lib ws2_32.lib
>   kernel32.lib' Win32Project2   C:\Users\Johan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Win32Project2\Win32Project2\LINK    1

I added the dependencies from `opengl32.lib` to `ws2_32.lib` because sfml-dev.org stated that the 5 main libraries were dependent on those. What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `SFML_STATIC` in the pre-processor options? I normally don't like linking to SFML libraries statically. Just put the libraries in the same directory of your executable and link to the dynamically.

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

Make sure to append your libraries with `-d` when you link to them if you're compiling a debug version, ex: `sfml-graphics-d`. Remove `-d` otherwise.

Comment: Yes I defined SFML_STATIC. I can try to use the Dynamic one.

I appended with -d in the Debug configuration, and without it in the Release configuration. Is that the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the appropriate DLL's in your project directory: Go to "bin" in your SFML folder, copy and paste everything, then go back to the folder that has all your source files for your project and paste there. Looking at your error message, it should be here:

> C:\Users\Johan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project2\Win32Project2\